# How can I get the work week and day number in VBA (outlook 2010)?

Tags: vba, outlook

We send out a daily email using Outlook that contains the work week and day in the format of WW.D Our work week starts on Monday, so like today would be 50.2 How can I add this using VBA?

```
Sub MakeItem()
    Dim objMail As MailItem   

    Set newItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Users\Update.oft")
    ' Work week number
    WW = 50.2

    ' Setup Subject replacing the <SHIFT>
    newItem.Subject = Replace("<WorkWeek> Shift Passdown ", "<WorkWeek>", WW)
    newItem.Display

    Set newItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WW = Format(Now, "ww") & "." & Weekday(Now, vbMonday)
```

The "Format" function returns an expression from a string formatted with the provided "format" argument (`ww` in this case, which returns the week of the year) and the `Weekday()` function returns the numbered day of the week where the first day is a `VBDayOfWeek` enumeration provided as the second argument (`vbMonday` in this case).